# Comparing two list and getting a new list in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list - a and a list of columns - b.

```
a = [2, 4, 1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 3, 5, 1]
b = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"]
```

I want to take the columns from list "b" which when compared with list "a" have the value 1.

I want the output to be:

```
c = ["C", "D", "F", "G", "J"]
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 9):

Easy task for comprehension + zip:

```
>>> c = [y for (x, y) in zip(a, b) if x == 1]
>>> c
['C', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'J']
```

Comment: Good answer but you don't need parentheses around `x, y`

Answer (score 3):

A classic approach:

```
>>> c = [b[i] for i in range(len(b)) if i<len(a) and a[i] == 1]
>>> c
['C', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'J']
```

Comment: We will get an index out of range error, in case list b is bigger than a :)

Comment: We won't now :) Check it!

Comment: Best is to iterate until len(a) :-) like "for i in range(len(a))"

Comment: No we can't since we get an index out of range error for `b[i]` in case list a is bigger than b :-)

Comment: That will be a new condition added. If list b being bigger than a, it is already covered as we can safely say that all the extra items in b are invalid.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it with zip and list comprehension.

```
>>> a = [2, 4, 1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 3, 5, 1]
>>> b = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"]
>>> c = [x[0] for x in zip(b, a) if x[1] == 1]
>>> c
['C', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'J']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Done in many ways:

**List Comprehension**

```
a = [2, 4, 1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 3, 5, 1]
b = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"]
print [b[index] for index, item in enumerate(a) if item == 1]
```

**Filter with Lambda**

```
a = [2, 4, 1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 3, 5, 1]
b = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"]
print filter(lambda index, item: len(a) > index and a[index]==1, enumerate(b))
```

Note that the list comprehension will be faster because it goes only up to the length of a rather than the list b, in case b is bigger.